# Enable cache for AJAX block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache, block-cache

I'm having problems with caching a block in Magento 2. The theme I'm using is getting content from the block via an AJAX call.

[image]

Is it possible how to cache such block in M2?

Thank you,
Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you rely on jQuery, add `cache: true` as the ajax call option.

This flag will instruct `$.ajax()` not to add the parameter which you mentioned in the comment.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Every block in magento2 is by default cacheable. You can disable cacheing of that block by explicitly adding cacheable="false" as the block attribute. Can you make sure that this attribute is not added anywhere for this particular block

Comment: The block itself is stored in cache, but the problem lies in something else. Everytime the block loads, there is an AJAX call made to ```/productfiler/index/firstload``` with some parameters. This loads the content of the block and this content is not cached and I need it to be.Do you have any ideas how to change that behaviour?

Comment: Either you can stop ajax loading the content and include that content in your block by coping all block information from productfiler_index_firstload to your block that is being cached. Or If you want to keep the ajax call then make sure that all blocks in productfiler_index_firstload.xml are cacheable. That means no block in there can have cacheable false attribute. We can be more helpful if you can provide both xmls

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, it's a widget that is placed in a CMS Block and this widget is actually making the AJAX call. And even worse, everything seems to be cached when I look at the code, the AJAX calls are still being made. How would you deal with that?